# Is it possible to use preseed/url with authentication?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, svn, deployment, preseed

We are using a preseed.cfg via preseed/url to automate system deployment/configuration.  The preseed files are kept in source control (Subversion).  This makes them readily available via HTTP, with the added bonus of being able to limit access. I'd like to reuse this resource, but I have not been able to find any way to use a preseed/url that requires authentication.  Is it possible to use a preseed url that requires authentication?

Comment: I can't test right now, but how about including the auth in your URL?  `http://username:password@server.example.com/path/to/preseed.cfg`

Comment: Looks like that does work in this case.  I'll give you credit if you post as answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP authorization info can be included in the URL, which most HTTP clients will translate automatically into the correct authorization headers:

```
http://username:password@server.example.com/path/to/preseed.cfg
```

This should do the trick!